# c++ template specialization: get template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

This runs:

```
template <class z>
struct u {z Z;};

template <int>
class n;

template <>
class n<3>: public u<int>
{
public:
    const int N = 3;
    n() : u({3}){}
};
```

But the repeated use of a magic number instead of template parameter is a risk of error.

This is unfortunately not possible:

```
template <int T = 3>
class n<T>: public u<int>
{
public:
    const int N = T;
    n() : u({T})
    {}
};
```

is there a better way?

Comment: Should `N` be `static constexpr` ? Then you might use `N` instead of `3`.

Comment: Your second example works fine for me if I write it as `template <int T = 3>` `class n: public u<int> { ... }`  (instead of `class n<T>...`)

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution.

Comment: This is not the solution because for the next value i get:                   error: redefinition of default argument for 'int T'

Comment: What do the other specializations look like?  There is no "partial" above?

Comment: the partial part is very different but not shown, the parameter is a enum not a int. Now is my way:                                                
 `template <>
#define T 1
class n<T>: public u<int>
{
 ...
public:
 n() : u(T) {}
};
#undef T`

Answer (score 0):

You might still use extra layer:

```
template <int Size>
class n_impl : public u<int>
{
public:
    const int N = Size;
    n() : u({Size}) {}
};

template <> class n<3> : n_impl<3> {};
```

Answer (score 0):

> the repeated use of a magic number instead of template parameter is a risk of error...

You could get rid of the repeating `3`, by simply wraping it up:

```
struct MagicNumber
{
    static constexpr int Number = 3;
};
```

Then your `n` goes:

```
template <>
class n<MagicNumber::Number>: public u<int>
{
public:
    n() : u(MagicNumber::Number){}
};
```

Comment: I'm looking for a safe variant, that the constructor u gets the template value. There are many realizations of n, not only in one file. Minimal risk of mistakes, despite copy and paste between similiar variants.